# jquery slider and mouseover code

Tags: jquery, html, css

All,

In the code below,

```
<html>
<head>
  <link type="text/css" href="http://jqueryui.com/latest/themes/base/ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>

<script src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/ui/effects.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/ui/effects.slide.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  #show { margin: 0px; width: 100px; height: 80px; background: green; border: 1px solid black; position: relative; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="details"  onmouseover="javascript:tooltip(this);">keyword</div>
<div id="show" style="display:none;"></div>
</body>

<script>
function tooltip(el)
{
    $("#details").mouseover(function() {
    $("#show").show("slide", {}, 1000);
    });
}
</script>
</html>
```

On mouse over keyword div. the green grid box  is suppose to be shown ans on mouse out it should.How is this achieved.

Thanks.............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that code inside mouseover function is never executed. When a mouseover even occurs, jQuery is used to reassign a function to mouseover, while it should be executed instead.

Make the following changes:

- Remove onmouseover from details div:

> ```
> <div id="details">keyword</div>
> ```

- Execute tooltop function when document is loaded by writing:

> ```
> <script>
> $(document).ready(function(){
> {
>     $("#details").mouseover(function() {
>         $("#show").show("slide", {}, 1000);
>     });
> }
> </script>
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You're attaching mouseover logic every time the user mouses over your element. You don't need to wrap this logic in a function, not in your case.

```
$(function(){
  $("#details").mouseover(function(){
    $("#show").show();
  });
});
```

Now the following line becomes obsolete:

```
<div id="details" onmouseover="javascript:tooltip(this);">
```

By writing `$("#details").mouseover()` we have already declared this logic. There's no need to place it in the mouseover attribute of the element via HTML now. You should be left with:

```
<div id="details">
```